# Why did Frank Underwood suddenly start playing a vowel game on a TV debate?

Tags: house-of-cards

In *House of Cards*, season 2, Frank Underwood goes onto a live TV debate after someone throws a brick into his house.

Frank Underwood is regarded as a very competent debater and he indeed holds his ground initially.

But Frank starts playing a silly vowel game on TV, it can be seen here.
[Vowel Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kmEYK_kgOQ)

I am wondering if Frank is doing it on purpose as this looks so out of place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He is just trying to be clever and fails miserably. Once he finds himself caught on the ropes in a debate concerning education, he tries to spin a sound byte from his unintentional pun ("there is no U / you and I in education'), momentarily becoming flustered upon realising the stupidity of what he has said before making the situation worse by 'inventing' an alphabet learning game in an attempt to school' his opponent - falling completely on his arse instead in the attempt.

It is obvious that Frank can be very clever and devious when he thinks he can control situations and has all the angles covered, but when genuinely lost for wards he cannot admit it.

Comment: I see, even for a person as calculating as Frank Underwood can fail.

Comment: I would say, from a personal POV, people who are as consistently as calculating as Frank inevitably fail in one manner or the other. My answer however is only based on my perception of Frank up to and including the 'Vowel Game' - I lost track of and subsequently interest in 'House Of Cards' after he became POTUS (end of S3 or so?)

Comment: The vowel game was also a bit of a show-off move, and another way he could dominate his opponent. Frank is a man obsessed with power after all.